# Не могу писать в Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь сделать самого просто чат-бота. Уже не получается, не могу писать в `Entry`. Код:

```
rom tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
root= Tk()
root.title("Чат - бот")
root.geometry("500x600")


def chat():
    name = Label(root,text = "Chat with Siri !!))")
    name.grid()
    chatx = Entry(root,width = 50)
    chatx.grid(row = 40,column=10,columnspan = 70)

messagebox.showinfo("","Siri")

chat()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если убрать messagebox, то нормально вводится.

Comment: Поздравляю,ты первый кто смог объяснить это самому глупому школьнику.P.S спасибо

Comment: Если нужен будет вывод messagebox, пробуйте его добавить в обработчиках событий (типа нажатий на кнопки), при таком способе использования я никогда особых проблем не замечал. Почему при вызове `messagebox` до `root.mainloop()` появляются такие глюки со вводом - я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: Я смотрю ты в tkinter разбираешься.Ты случайно не знаешь можно ли после ответа стирать текст?

Comment: Смотря где стирать. Можете задать вопрос, я посмотрю.

Comment: Уже сделал.Можешь смотреть